# Outlook adding transform to mail template

Tags: css, email, templates, outlook, transform

I am styling a mail template and making it responsive for mobile, tablet and of course desktop. But the problem i have now is that outlook is adding transform: scale(0.8375); in the css of my table which is causing the mail template to become very small on ipad because it is not using full width. I have tried putting the transform on none and some other options you have but nothing is working because it seems that outlook is just stripping that out and just sticks to transform: scale(0.8375). Does anyone know how i can fix this ?.

Comment: Can you share your code and a screenshot of the rendering on iPad? Auto-scaling is a common procedure for email clients whenever an email does not fit the viewport.

Comment: <table style="padding-left: 0px; padding-right: 0px; padding-top: 0px; border-spacing: 0px; transform: scale(0.695833); transform-origin: left top 0px;" min-scale="0.6958333333333333" width="650" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="20" border="1"> This is how outlook be adding the transform.

Comment: I meant the code of your entire email. As I said, if the email client auto-scales your email, it means your email does not fit the viewport. So either your responsive code is broken or you might have to adapt another coding approach (like mobile first or fluid/hybrid). Showing your code is the best way to let us help yourself.